# Cron jobs over 100 per minute, too many?

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

Hello I have a server with 100 client sites, each with its own database.
I need each one to run a cron job every minutes 24/7 to check to see if the client
has set a post to publish at that time, if so set `is_published` to 1 in the post table.
My question is, without benchmark testing available, is 100 cron jobs every minute going to slow down my server significantly? I know this is vague, but I am running a Linux server with 1024MB of ram on a 10MBps port.

Comment: There's nothing special about cron jobs, they're just like any other process.

Comment: The workload isn't too heavy, but there are surely better ways to handle the objective. You can determine when each post is due, and keep a [delta-list](http://everything2.com/title/delta+list) of the jobs and the time to go until the job is to be published.  Monitor that list.  As new jobs arrive, they go into the list.  If you need 100 lists, one per site (so each publisher doesn't know when others have set articles to be published), so be it; you can maintain an integrated list which includes the site/database ID information as well as the article info and publication time information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a bad idea, for a number of reasons.  Load on the server is one of them.  Do you really want to invest your hardware dollars in setting the flag `is_published` in hundreds of databases?  Do clients care about the up-to-one minute lag?  What happens if the number of clients grows more quickly than you expect?

There is an easier way.  Just have a column with `PostedTime` in the `posts` table.  Then create a view that uses this column:

```
create view v_posts as
    select p.*, (PostedTime >= now()) as is_published
    from posts;
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic idea! I would not have thought of that. That actually solves many problems for me. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

It just a bit more that 1 request per second. If the cron jobs are distributed evenly within that minute, and if the cron job is really simple and fast, I can't see where the problem could be.