# Inserting data in a particular column where login id is already present

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write an sql command in PHP in which I want to insert a data in a particular column having particular data already present in that row.Here is the image where I want to insert 1_day_device to a particular 1_day_id

[image]

Also, how can I autodelete a row after a certain time? Like, in the image I want to delete one complete row after one day. I am using PHP for server-side.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for `replace` query

Comment: See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am getting data from two different sources. First, I get 1_day_id from one source then I get 1_day_device from another source. Now "996609" should get "bdb*********" but right now it's in another row. Similarly, for id "1595281" I want to insert "3cf4********" in that row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the update query with particular 1_day_id. Try with the below query.

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET 1_day_device='".$device."' WHERE 1_day_data='".$data."'
```

For delteting the records please follow this link [Delete row from database automatically after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697891/delete-row-from-database-automatically-after-24-hours)

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_**` based functions, as they are no longer supported, use `mysqli_***` or `PDO` instead. Additionally please reference the use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection.